# issue in redirecting after form submission in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've a simple form

```
<form:form commandName="user">
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form:form>
```

through which I get data and save in Database using

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User construct(){
        return new User();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "users";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String showRegiteratinForm() {
        return "user-register";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doRegiteratin(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        userService.save(user);
        return "users";

    }

}
```

and want to show all users

```
<P>  The User on the server are </P>
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <p>${user.name}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

on users page using

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IDbCrud<User>{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userRepository.save(obj);
    }

}
```

data is inserted, but issue is no data/user is showed at user page and if I change form to this

```
<form:form commandName="user" action="/context/users">
    <form:input path="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form:form>
```

I get all users which are already saved but the last one is not saved. How to do the trick for get this work accordingly.

Comment: Please provide the body of **UserRepository.save()**  method and please make sure that you are calling transac.commit() and session.flush() method

Comment: got any caching on server or browser? did you check that the record is in the db?

Comment: You are posting to the wrong URL. Your form should go to `/register` not `/users` as that isn't going to do anything.

Comment: And the register method should redirect, not forward to the users view. `return "redirect:/users";`